# Previously perfect C program doesn't run after compiling on Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, compilation, execution

I have a strange problem. I wrote a C program for point in polygon (pip) problem, and when I wrote it, I use Elementary OS. The program ran very well. Then I had to switch to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, because I couldn't install netCdf on Elementary OS Luna. I copied the pip program to the new system, and I wanted to run it. I complied the program (no errors), and then ran it. The program ran well while it reached "for" cycles which contain functions. When it reached them, the program didn't write error message, it ran further (CPU: 100% ) and didn't stop itself.

I don't understand what the problem is. There is a program which had run perfectly on an OS, and doesn't run well on an other. I didn't change anything in the program. And I have also tried to make a new .c file in which I copied the program, but It made the same problem.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks for your helps!

I compiling the program with that command:

```
cc pipn.c -o pipn.exe
```

And run with a .run file: (.c and .txt in Documents folder, no subfolder)

```
binPath=/home/bajogh/Documents


#n latNa lonNa latNb lonNb dx dy
${binPath}/pipn.exe 13 85.0 -180.0 0.0 179.5 0.5 0.5
```

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int innerpoint(int n, float *lon, float *lat, float lon0, float lat0)
{
    int i, j, c = 0;

    for (i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; j = i++) {
        if ((((lat[i] <= lat0) && (lat0 < lat[j])) ||
            ((lat[j] <= lat0) && (lat0 < lat[i]))) &&
            (lon0 < (lon[j] - lon[i]) * (lat0 - lat[i]) / (lat[j] - lat[i]) + lon[i]))
            c = !c;
    }
    return c;
}//pip?=1, pip!=0

int vertex(int n, float *lon, float *lat, float lon0, float lat0)
{
    int i, c = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i = i++) {
        if ((lat[i] == lat0) && (lon[i] == lon0))
            c = !c;
    } 
    return c;
} //testpoint is a vertex?

int sidepoint(int n, float *lon, float *lat, float lon0, float lat0)
{
    int i, j, c = 0;

    for (i = 0, j = n - 1; i < n; j = i++)
    {
        if (((lat[i] <= lat0) && (lat0 <= lat[j])) || ((lat[j] <= lat0) && (lat0 <= lat[i])))
            if (((lon[i] <= lon0) && (lon0 <= lon[j])) || ((lon[j] <= lon0) && (lon0 <= lon[i])))
            if ((((lat0 - lat[i])*(lon[j] - lon[i])) - ((lon0 - lon[i])*(lat[j] - lat[i]))) == 0)
                c=!c;
    }

    return c;
}//testpoint is on a side?

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fp,*finout,*fin;
    fp = fopen("polygon.txt", "r");             //polygon coordinates, 2 columns: lon lat
    finout = fopen("pip_inout.txt", "w");   
    fin = fopen("pip_in.txt", "w");         

    float *lon0;    
    float *lat0;    
    float *lon; 
    float *lat; 
    float dx,dy;
    float latNa,lonNa; 
    float latNb,lonNb; 
    int nx,ny;  
    int q,l;    
    int p,n;    

    n=atoi(argv[1]);
    latNa=atof(argv[2]);
    lonNa=atof(argv[3]);
    latNb=atof(argv[4]);
    lonNb=atof(argv[5]);
    dx=atof(argv[6]);
    dy=atof(argv[7]);

//polygon -------------------------------------------

    //printf("Number of vertices of polygon?\n");
    //scanf("%d",&n);
     printf("Number of verticies of polygon: %d\n",n);  
    if((lon=(float *)calloc(n,sizeof(float)))==NULL)
    {
        printf("can't alloc for lon\n");
        fprintf(stderr,"can't alloc for lon\n");
        return (3);
    }
    if((lat=(float *)calloc(n,sizeof(float)))==NULL)
    {
        printf("can't alloc for lat\n");
        fprintf(stderr,"can't alloc for lat\n");
        return(3);
    }   
    for (p=0;p<n;p++)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%f %f", &lon[p],&lat[p]);
    }

    for (p=0;p<n;p++)
    {
        printf("%11.5f %11.5f\n", lon[p],lat[p]);
    }
    printf("---------------------------------------\n");

//testpoints

    nx=((abs(lonNa)+abs(lonNb))/dx)+2;
    ny=((abs(latNa)+abs(latNb))/dy)+1;
    printf("nx=%d ny=%d\n",nx,ny);
    printf("---\n");

    if((lon0=(float *)calloc(nx,sizeof(float)))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"can't alloc for lon0\n");
        return(3);
    }
    if((lat0=(float *)calloc(ny,sizeof(float)))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"can't alloc for lat0\n");
        return(3);
    }

    for(q=0;q<ny;q++)
    {
          lat0[q]=latNa-(dy*q);
           for(l=0;l<nx;l++)
       {
        lon0[l]=lonNa+(dx*l);
        printf("%f %f\n",lat0[q],lon0[l]);
       }
    }

    printf("----------------------------------------\n");

//START OF THE PROBLEMATIC SECTION 

    for (q = 0; q<ny; q++)
    {
      for(l=0;l<nx;l++)
      {
        if (vertex(n, lon, lat, lon0[l], lat0[q]) == 1)
            {printf("%11.5f %11.5f     1\n", lat0[q], lon0[l]);
             fprintf(finout,"%11.5f %11.5f     1\n", lat0[q], lon0[l]);
             fprintf(fin,"%11.5f %11.5f\n", lat0[q], lon0[l]);} 
        else
             if (sidepoint(n, lon, lat, lon0[l], lat0[q]) == 1)
                {printf("%11.5f %11.5f     1\n", lat0[q], lon0[l]);
                fprintf(finout,"%11.5f %11.5f     1\n", lat0[q], lon0[l]);
                fprintf(fin,"%11.5f %11.5f\n", lat0[q], lon0[l]);} 
            else
                 if (innerpoint(n, lon, lat, lon0[l], lat0[q]) == 1)
                    {printf("%11.5f %11.5f     1\n", lat0[q], lon0[l]);
                    fprintf(finout,"%11.5f %11.5f     1\n", lat0[q], lon0[l]);
                    fprintf(fin,"%11.5f %11.5f\n", lat0[q], lon0[l]);} 
                else
                    {printf("%11.5f %11.5f     0\n", lat0[q], lon0[l]);
                    fprintf(finout,"%11.5f %11.5f     0\n", lat0[q], lon0[l]);}
       }
    }


    printf("-------!!!COMPLETED!!!--------\n");
    printf("---< In-points in 'pip_in.txt' >---\n");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: So you expect us to build that and run it in a debugger for you? Shouldn't you try that before posting here?

Comment: Sorry, I am new in C programming. I don't know these debugger options. But I tried a lot of different ways to solve my problem, but I failed. Sorry, if it is bother you. I have got the answer from ouah, and it solved my problem. After that I am ashamed that I didn't recognize it.

Comment: Not exactly "Previously perfect C program".  The bug fix is needed, but not sufficient to make it such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `vertex`:

```
i = i++
```

is undefined behavior in C: you may get different results with different compilers.

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my problem. I don't why I didn't recognize it...

Answer (score 1):

Compiling with clang points to the problem immediately:

```
clang t1.c
t1.c:21:29: warning: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]
    for (i = 0; i < n; i = i++) {
                         ~  ^
1 warning generated.
```

There are other problems with your code:

- you test for `malloc` failure, but not for `fopen` or if there are not enough command line arguments.
- you should be using `double` instead of `float` types.
- the logic in `innerpoint`, `vertex` and `sidepoint` looks wrong to me.  You toggle `c` when there is a match.  These functions will return `0` if there is an even number of matches, for example if you have empty segments.  This may be correct for `innerpoint` but is probably wrong for `vertex`.